# Dynamic column calculation

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a SQL query which will return a string of columns that needs to be summed up in a table.

however, I am unable to use that string dynamically and calculate from table..

example if my Query 1 is returning 'column_a+column_b+column_c' as string

I want to use that string and calculate from table  'select column_a+column_b+column_c from table'

can some body please help, how to use this in snowflake SQL? and for some reasons, we cannot create stored procedure.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output ? also add your attempt

Comment: Please see the above comment, and say why "for some reasons, we cannot create stored procedure" -> what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

If your query can fit in <=256 characters, you could use session variables with `execute immediate`

```
 create or replace temporary table t as
 select 1 as col1, 2 as col2, 3 as col3;

 set sum_cols = 'col1+col2+col3';
 set stmt = 'select ' || $sum_cols || ' from t;';

 execute immediate $stmt;
```